# Traducción errónea en página de privilegios del Centro de ayuda: "baja cualidad" en lugar de "baja calidad"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

En este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit se explica al usuario el privilegio que se obtiene al alcanzar los 2000 ptos y en el ultimo parrafo dice lo siguiente:

> Además de revisar las ediciones sugeridas, también pasa a estar disponible la cola de publicaciones de baja calidad. Esta cola contiene publicaciones consideradas de **baja cualidad** por parte de nuestro sistema. Los usuarios están encargados de editar para mejorar su formato y contenido, recomendar su eliminación si no pertenece a nuestro sitio o marcarlas como una publicación aceptable.

Creo que en vez de ser **baja cualidad** deberia decir **baja calidad**, o bien redactarse de otra forma

Comment: Cualidad -> Característica que se considera buena o positiva. Origen
Del latín qualitas, qualitatis . Del mismo origen que cualidad (V.).

Comment: @gbianchi, hola, por fin que hay con esto?